# C2440 Create 2D Array with Shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create 2D array with shared_ptr, but I have an error `C2440`.

I think I write right codes, but error occured..

Please help me, thank you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    int size;
    std::cout << "Input size : ";
    std::cin >> size;
    std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int[]>[]> myArr(new std::shared_ptr<int[]>[size]);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        myArr[i] = std::make_shared<int[]>(size);         // error..

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            myArr[i][j] = (j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed follwoing code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    myArr[i] = std::make_shared<int[]>(size);         // error..
```

into :

```
myArr[i] = std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[size]);
```

Making array with `shared_ptr`, you cannot use `make_shared`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop is (loosely) trying to perform the following through `std::make_shared` which is an error:

```
int *t = int*[];  // ERROR
```

Instead, you can directly create a shared pointer and assign it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    myArr[i] = std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[size]);
```

There is a caveat when using directly `std::shared_ptr(new T)` instead of
`std::make_shared<T>(...)`, however in this case you cannot use the latter.